# how can i run this root calculator code for big numbers such as 1e50?

Tags: java, math, double

this code is using newton-rapshon method for calculating the approximate root however, not stopping when trying to calculate numbers which greater than 1e49. How can i fix it, can u help me ?..

Code:

```
public static double e=0.0001;
public static double root;


public static double sqrt (double x ) {
    
    root = (x/2);
    
    while(root*root-x>e ||  root*root-x< -e) {
    
    root=((1.0/2)*(root+x/root));
    
    }
    
    return root;

    
}

public static void main ( String [ ] Args) {
    
    System.out.println(csMath.sqrt(1e50));
}
```

}

Comment: Please tag the programming language you are using.

Comment: What other datatypes for numbers does whatever language this is support?

Comment: language is java sorry... i missed that

Comment: 1e50 is not that big. But you might consider a relative error tolerance rather than an absolute error tolerance.